# identifying screen cutout position in flutter

Tags: flutter, display-cutouts

My app has a search bar in its top area. There are devices with special [cutouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout). in order to expand the app to real full screen, I Added to `<app_name>\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<style name="ActivityTheme">
  <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges
  </item>
</style>
```

That works fine. However, the obvious next step is to recognize cutout position, and place the search bar accordingly:

[image: cutout options]

The mentioned documentation refers to a `JAVA` method `WindowInsets.getDisplayCutout()`. I wonder if there is an equivalent in `flutter` or a plugin which wraps it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [SafeArea widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) that will add insets so that you can avoid device. I'd give this a try - I know it works with common features like the iphone top cutout and the android camera.